# How to avoid singular gradient matrix error when using nlsLM?

Tags: r, nls

`y` is the number of deaths due to CovId-19 in the United States between 3/1/2020 and 4/22/2020:

```
y <- c(1,6,9,11,12,15,19,22,26,30,38,41,48,58,73,95,121,171,239,309,374,509,689,957,1260,1614,2110,2754,3251,3948,5027,6263,7438,8694,10231,11632,13128,15347,17503,19604,21830,23843,25558,27272,29825,32443,34619,37147,39014,40575,42514,45179,47520)

View(y)

k <- length(t(y))

n <- y[k]
```

These are the normalized y values:

```
normy=y/n

View(normy)

t = 1:k

library(minpack.lm)
```

Next; we give the model an initial "kick-start" by assigning initial values to the parameters a, b, c, d, beta:

```
fitmodel <- nlsLM(normy~(a/(1+d*((1+c)/(beta+exp(b*t))))), 
                  start=list(a=500,b=0.15,c=2.5,d=30,beta=-10))
```

After running the above code in R I get the following error message:

> Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) :
> singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates.

In addition; I get the following Warning message:

> In nls.lm(par = start, fn = FCT, jac = jac, control = control, lower = lower,  :
> lmdif: info = -1. Number of iterations has reached `maxiter' == 50.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you can you should look to see how well your function fits the data at your starting parameters: `fun = function(t, a=500,b=0.15,c=2.5,d=30,beta=-10) a/(1+d*((1+c)/(beta+exp(b*t)))); plot(t, y); lines(t, fun(t))` is not a good fit. But I think the main issue is your function is over-parameterised --  I_think_ you could reduce it to `1 + c/(beta + exp(b*t))`

Comment: Please, download the following article for more information about this model: https://res.mdpi.com/d_attachment/mathematics/mathematics-08-00655/article_deploy/mathematics-08-00655-v2.pdf  Thank you!